# ZeroMQ, ROUTER - DEALER, send a message to all

Tags: zeromq

One server - ZMQ_ROUTER, many clients - ZMQ_DEALER

How on a server(ZMQ_ROUTER) send a message to all clients(ZMQ_DEALER)?

UPD:
I know there are PUB-SUB pattern and that is really what I need. But I want to use only the current ROUTER-DEALER socket. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but It won't be the answer you would like to hear. I think there isn't a flag, or socket option for this. What you can do:

Track the connected `dealers` manually, than create a loop and send the same stuff to every connected dealer. If you send large messages you can [zero copy](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Zero-Copy) the load, so you don't have to allocate the memory time to time.

Comment: Yes, seems it is the only way.